# Login + Password identification

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I'm trying to create a batch video uploading app for Youtube in C#. The problem is, I don't really know (and it's also not specified in API Documentation) how to handle using the app with multiple accounts (ie. video1 uploads with user1/pass1, video2 uploads with user2/pass2 combinations).

AFAIK I can only upload to my own channel, using OAUTH2, my own secret and ID and I can't use any type of other authentication? Is that correct or can I use login/pass combinations somehow?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us which API you're using...

Comment: As i stated in the title - Official google Youtube api v3